Progress Bar in React native paper
I have added a progress bar using react native paper but unable to make the filled section rounded, though the unfilled section has rounded corners
import { ProgressBar } from 'react-native-paper'; 


<ProgressBar style={styles.progressBarStyle} fillStyle={styles.fillStyle}  progress={progress} color="#0053A6" />

progressBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
    height: 12,
    borderRadius: 64,
  },
  fillStyle: {
    borderRadius: 64,
  },


Your code works for me. Have you tried overflow: 'hidden' inside fillStyle?
